# Chain celery tasks and pass return from one task to another implicitly

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to do the following

```
@shared_task
def task1():
    return '1'

@shared_task
def task2(r1):
    return '2'

@shared_task
def task3(r2):
    return 'done'

@shared_task
def job():
    chain = (task1.s() | task2.s() | task3.s() ).apply_async()
    chain()
```

But I have to give `task2` and `task3` argument explicitly, otherwise I would get error.

What can I do to let result flow to the next task?

Comment: What issue are you running into from what I see this should run

Answer (score 7):

You can directly pass additional arguments to a subtask without changing anything.

```
chain = (task1.s() | task2.s(r1) | task3.s(r2) ).apply_async()
```

Here task1 accepts no arguments, task2 accepts two arguments, first is the result of previous task and the second one is `r1`. Same for task3 also.

If you don't need result of task1 in task2 then you can make signature of task2 as immutable.

```
chain = (task1.s() | task2.si(r1) | task3.s(r2) ).apply_async()
```

Here task1 accepts no arguments, task2 only one argument `r1`. Task3 accepts two arguments, first is the result of previous task and the second one is `r2`

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the job part a bit:

```
@shared_task
def job():
    chain = (task1.s() | task2.s() | task3.s() )
    result = chain().get()
    return result
```

Since the execution of one is dependent on it's preceding task you don't get anything by applying it asynchronously.  You can start job asynchronously however.

This is not good practice thou and [should be avoided](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks).

Comment: You should not have a task waiting for the result of another: taskhttp://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#avoid-launching-synchronous-subtasks

Comment: Avoid is not synonymous with never. Answered the question as asked.  I'll add the link and a warning.  You are right that if you have complex task structures (or load chokes your infrastructure) you can end in a deadlock.